# Unity Toggle Button Delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make it so my toggle = !toggle doesn't just repeat OVER and OVER when you press it once because it kind of toggles on and off over and over if you hold it it just keeps toggling like 30 times a second and I want it to have a delay here is the gist of my code

```
private class AirJump_Patch
{
  private static void Postfix (Locomotion.Player __instance)
   {
    List<InputDevice> list = new List<InputDevice>();
    InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(InputDeviceCharacteristics.HeldInHand | 
    InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller | InputDeviceCharacteristics.Right, list);
    list[0].TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.secondaryButton, out 
    Plugin.AirJump_Patch.secondaryButton);

    if (Plugin.AirJump_Patch.secondaryButton)
     {
      Plugin.AirJump_Patch.jumpToggled = !Plugin.AirJump_Patch.jumpToggled;
     }
    if (!Plugin.AirJump_Patch.jumpToggled)
     {
      //DO CODE
     }
ECT ECT.
```

I tried adding delay using StartCoroutine, doesn't work
I tried adding delay using simple C# wait things, doesn't work
This is in a private static void. I cannot change that. Is there a reasonably easy way to make the toggle **not** repeat 30 times a second with a 0.5 second delay or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use a simple timer field like

```
private float lastToggle;
```

and then

```
if(Time.time > lastToggle + 0.5f) 
{ 
    lastToggle = Time.time; 

    Plugin.AirJump_Patch.jumpToggled = !Plugin.AirJump_Patch.jumpToggled; 
}
```

---

Alternatively you could actually handle it really only once e.g. like

```
private bool alreadyToggled;

if(Plugin.AirJump_Patch.secondaryButton)
{
    if(!alreadyToggled)
    {
        Plugin.AirJump_Patch.jumpToggled = !Plugin.AirJump_Patch.jumpToggled;
        alreadyToggled = true;
    }
}
else
{
    alreadyToggled = false;
}
```

now it is really only handled once per button press.